# Autoconfiguation excluded but embedded servlet container is still being used

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I've followed all the steps mentioned in the documentation to enable the traditional war deployment for spring boot app i.e excluded the `EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration` from the `@EnableAutoConfiguration` and I only have one such instance. Also extended `SpringBootServletInitializer` and make sure the packaged war doesnt have any tomcat starter dependency. Also ran the spring boot report and confirmed the `EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration` is in the exclusion list.

Apart from all the changes when I deploy the war it is still creating a embedded application context with embedded servlet contatiner.

What did I miss and what other areas can I inspect ? Spring boot version 1.5.13.

Comment: post your code... check mvn dependency:tree so that nothing else is pulling in tomcat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

>

Hi [Veeram](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2683814/veeram),

We do not need to exclude the `AutoConfiguration-classes`, but excluding the `tomcat` dependency is needed.

You need to do is omit `tomcat starter` dependency from `pom.xml`. It gets pulled from `spring-boot-starter-web` as a transitive dependency. So, you need to add exclusion for it:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Now, as you are using `<packaging>war</packaging>` and using `SpringBootServletInitializer`, we would need `servlet-api` dependency on the classpath.

So, add the servlet dependency to your `pom.xml`

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Hope this helps!